# create pdf thumbnail with pdfjs in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11, pdf.js

I want to show the first page of a pdf file as an image.
As far as I can see, I can´t do that with the typescript library "ng2-pdf-viewer" and therefore need to use the javascript library "pdfjs-dist".
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982049/10190273) describing how to create a thumbnail with pdfjs.

On "ng serve" I get the following error message:

```
Error: ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 2205:45
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2205:45)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         intent: renderingIntent,
|         renderInteractiveForms: renderInteractiveForms === true,
>         annotationStorage: annotationStorage?.serializable || null
|       });
|     }
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712766/10190273) describing how to solve this by changing the angular builder.
Then however I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
```

I can only find mentions of this error in angular 9.

**Therefore my questions:**

- **Is it really necessary to use a custom builder?**
- **How can I fix "Cannot read property 'flags'" in angular 11?**

I´m using the following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.13",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.7.4",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.8.335",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself after updating angular to version 12.2.4:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { getDocument, GlobalWorkerOptions, version } from 'pdfjs-dist';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DocumentService {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;
  }

  public getPdfThumbnail(pdfUrl: string) {
    return from(getDocument(pdfUrl).promise)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(pdf => from(pdf.getPage(1))),
      switchMap(page => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2 });
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        return from(page.render({
          canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D,
          viewport
        }).promise)
        .pipe(
          map(() => canvas)
        );
      }),
      switchMap(canvas => {
        return new Observable<SafeUrl>(observer => {
          canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            if (blob) {
              observer.next(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
              observer.complete();
            }
          }, 'image/jpeg', 0.75);
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting Error: ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 2164:21 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2164:21) error. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try running npm update. That´s what I did alongside updating angular. Changing module to a newer ECMA-Version in tsconfig.json might also help.

Comment: use this import {getDocument, GlobalWorkerOptions, version} from "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js"; when you get error Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2164:21) error instead of import { getDocument, GlobalWorkerOptions, version } from 'pdfjs-dist';